# Find Simulink Requirements and get their contents

Tags: matlab, validation, verification, simulink, requirements

I find the requirements by searching for subsystems, as there seems to be no special block for requirements.

```
find_system(gcs,'LookUnderMasks','none','FollowLinks','off','BlockType','SubSystem','LinkStatus','none')
```

I get all the subsystems, including :

```
'test_simulinkmodel/SLVnV Internal Requirement Sub Block Name 1'
```

Is there some other way than to look for this (default?)string?

Also, when I know the path, is there some way to get the contents (Titles, descriptions?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which release are you using? In the latest release (R2013a), there is the [System Requirements](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/slvnv/ref/systemrequirements.html) block. You can also generate (and customize) a [requirements report](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/slvnv/ug/create-and-customize-requirements-report.html), which should also work in earlier releases (I remember using it in R2011a for example).

Comment: I'm using R2013a, but it does not work to search for find_system(gcs,'BlockType','System Requirements')

and the block is not included in this list:
http://www.mathworks.se/help/simulink/blocklist.html

Comment: The block is part of Simulink Verification & Validation, so if you have a license for that, it should automatically list all the requirements associated with the model when placed in the model. Alternatively, you can generate a requirements as previously mentioned.

Comment: I see the requirements in the model, but I'm doing an export from simulink to another application, an there i need to get the Requirement title (at least) and Description from the model programaticaly. I could also parse the mdl-file, but then I cant cope with slx files. The report generation would require me to do a parser for HTML as well, which feels a bit overkill.

Comment: OK. If you want a programmatic interface to the requirements in a model, I believe it's through the `rmi` function (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/slvnv/ref/rmi.html), although I haven't got any experience of it.

Answer (score 0):

In the R2017b release, MathWorks released a new product called [Simulink Requirements](https://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink-requirements.html) that lets you author and manage requirements within Simulink.  You can link requirements to design objects in Simulink as well as to test cases and their results.